# Xamarin forms circle with two colors

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am trying to get a hang of Xamarin Forms with XAML. I now want to accomplish below. I have tried circles, Prohressbars and chart but no effect. Anyone an idee on how?
I need to be able to set left and right color. and text.

[image]

Comment: Draw two arcs with different strokes. Or put a circle mask over two rects. Also I'm answering with universal XAML capabilities, not xamarin-specific, thus commenting

Comment: Thank you Stephen, that put me in the correct direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> you can draw it by using **skiasharp**/**curves**/**arcs**

```
void OnCanvasViewPaintSurface(object sender, SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs args)
{
    SKImageInfo info = args.Info;
    SKSurface surface = args.Surface;
    SKCanvas canvas = surface.Canvas;

    canvas.Clear();

    SKRect rect = new SKRect(100, 100, info.Width - 100, info.Height - 100);
    float startAngle = (float)startAngleSlider.Value;
    float sweepAngle = (float)sweepAngleSlider.Value;

    canvas.DrawOval(rect, outlinePaint);

    using (SKPath path = new SKPath())
    {
        path.AddArc(rect, startAngle, sweepAngle);
        canvas.DrawPath(path, arcPaint);
    }
}
```

> [See the Full Description and  Doc here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/curves/arcs)

Comment: Thank you @ArunPratap for the help I got it to work :)